# tikz ´draw ... to ...´ combined with ´node´ along path

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-node

I have found a strange behavior in TikZ. When using the `\draw ... to ...` syntax and trying to place nodes along the line with the `node[...]{...}` syntax, the nodes do not turn up at the expected location.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0) to[out=60,in=120] (1,0) node[midway]{x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: strange position]

How is this done properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \draw(0,0) to[out=60,in=120] node {x}  (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead nodes you can use here `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0) to [out=60,in=120, "x"] (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid stating `above` and have the node directly on the arrow?

Comment: Yes, for `tikzpiczure` use option `auto`. See edit of my answer.