# node above tikz path does not works with "--" but not "to"

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am struggling with the positioning of a node above a tikz path. The path is curved and connects two nodes with "to". Here is a MVE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,transform shape]
\draw[->,thick,out=0,in=180] (1,0) to (5,1) node[above,pos=0.5,sloped] {text};
\draw[->,thick] (1,3) -- (5,4) node[above,pos=0.5,sloped] {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The node is above the line in the case with "--" but not with the "to". What I am missing here? 
I am pretty sure I had something similar working in the past...

Comment: You need to place `node ..` immediately after `to`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424607 Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381342

Comment: See also: [PGF/TiKZ: When should I choose "--", "to" or "edge" to connect nodes? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646403/pgf-tikz-when-should-i-choose-to-or-edge-to-connect-nodes)